# How do you allow 400 Errors to propagate when using Feign with Hystrix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign

I'm building a SpringBoot microservice that calls another microservice and naturally want to use Hystrix and Feign clients, which are both included with Spring Cloud. I'm using version Camden.SR5.

For any timeouts, connection failures and 50x response codes from Feign, I want Hystrix to kick in and work as normal: tripping the circuit breaker and calling the fallback (if configured), etc. It does this by default, so I'm good.

But for 40x response codes, which include things like invalid entry, the wrong format of fields etc, I want Hystrix to propagate these exceptions to the caller, so I can handle them as I choose too. This isn't the default I've observed. *How do you configure Hystrix/Feign to do this in Spring Cloud?*

Out of the box using the following code:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@FeignClient(name = "dog-service", url = "http://...")
public interface DogsFeignClient {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/dogs")
  Resource<Dog> createDog(Dog dog);
}
```

Generates this exception, which doesn't lend itself to nicely passing that 40x response back to the caller:

```
com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: DogsFeignClient#createDog(Dog) failed and no fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:805) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    ....lines ommited for brevity....
Caused by: feign.FeignException: status 400 reading DogsFeignClient#createDog(Dog); content:
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "entity" : "Dog",
    "property" : "numberOfLegs",
    "invalidValue" : "3",
    "message" : "All dogs must have 4 legs"
  } ]
}
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62) ~[feign-core-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91) ~[feign-core-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[feign-core-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76) ~[feign-core-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108) ~[feign-hystrix-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:301) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:297) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

I can of course look at the `com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException`, `cause` field which contains a `feign.FeignException` and buried in the description is the JSON response itself, with line breaks and such. But the `cause` field of `feign.FeignException` is a reference to itself. Is there a way to get a deeper exception propagated instead of the HystrixRuntimeException?

Also is there a way to get the raw body included with the response from the downstream service, so I don't have to deconstruct the message field of the nested exception?

Comment: I'd say disable feigns hystrix integration, implement an error decoder that throws a special exception for those cases and use a `HystrixCommand` object or `@HystrixCommand` annotation and ignore certain exceptions.

Answer (score 15):

This can be achieved using a separate configuration, which will wrap 400's in a subclass of `HystrixBadRequestException` and throw them to the client code.
These exceptions don't affect the circuit breaker state - if the circuit is closed, it will remain closed, and if it's open, it will remain open.

```
@FeignClient(name = "dog-service", 
             url = "http://...", 
             configuration=FeignPropagateBadRequestsConfiguration.class)
public interface DogsFeignClient {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/dogs")
  Resource<Dog> createDog(Dog dog);
}
```

where `FeignPropagateBadRequestsConfiguration` is

```
@Configuration
public class FeignSkipBadRequestsConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
        return (methodKey, response) -> {
            int status = response.status();
            if (status == 400) {
                String body = "Bad request";
                try {
                    body = IOUtils.toString(response.body().asReader());
                } catch (Exception ignored) {}
                HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                response.headers().forEach((k, v) -> httpHeaders.add("feign-" + k, StringUtils.join(v,",")));
                return new FeignBadResponseWrapper(status, httpHeaders, body);
            }
            else {
                return new RuntimeException("Response Code " + status);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and `FeignBadResponseWrapper` is

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class FeignBadResponseWrapper extends HystrixBadRequestException {
    private final int status;
    private final HttpHeaders headers;
    private final String body;

    public FeignBadResponseWrapper(int status, HttpHeaders headers, String body) {
        super("Bad request");
        this.status = status;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

This is a bit of a hack, and you can get the response body only in `ErrorDecoder`, because after that the stream will be closed. But using this, you can throw the response data to client code without affecting the circuit:

```
    try {
        return dogsFeignClient.createDog(dog);
    } catch (HystrixBadRequestException he) {
        if (he instanceof FeignBadResponseWrapper) {
            // obtain data from wrapper and return it to client
        } else {
            // return basic error data for other exceptions
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! solved my problem, but there is a small name error: `FeignSkipBadRequestsConfiguration` should be `FeignPropagateBadRequestsConfiguration`

Comment: the sharpest solution! Thanks man!